# How to make a blocking call with async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

how can I make this call blocking (using, for example, the async/await)?

```
testMethod(message) {
    let signature;
    eccrypto.sign(this.privateKey, msg)
        .then(function (sig) {
            console.log("Signature in DER format:", sig);
            signature = sig;
        });
    return signature;
}
```

I'd like testMethod to return `signature`, right now return (of course) `undefined`! I've been playing with `async/await` with no success ...

any help?

Comment: async/await are just ways to work with promises with nicer syntax. They don't stop async code being async.

Comment: A minor thing, but you're using `message` in your function definition, but `msg` in your call to `eccrypto.sign`. Is that intentional? Which leads me to another point, you should always handle your errors, either using `.catch()` if using old-school promise syntax, or try/catch if using async/await

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do async/await. Like this

```
async testMethod(message) {
    let signature;
    signature = await eccrypto.sign(this.privateKey, msg)
        .then(function (sig) {
            console.log("Signature in DER format:", sig);
            return sig;
        });
    return signature;
}
```

But it won't be blocking. It would work similar to synchromous code but it's not the same. See for [details](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: That is not correct syntax for async/await.

Comment: Why so? As I undestand, the testMethod is a class method

Comment: Yes, the async part is correct, but the third line should be `signature = await eccrypto.sign(...`

The await goes right before the async function call

Comment: oh, yeah. My fault. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
async testMethod(msg) {
    try {
      const signature = await eccrypto.sign(this.privateKey, msg)
      console.log('Signature in DER format:', signature);
      return signature;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error generating signature', e.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Could you consider adding some additional information explaining your answer.